Returning from UK to Belgium, but my daughters' titre de sejour is expired
I'm travelling to the UK on Eurostar with my daughters who have US passports but we're renewing their titre de sejour. Will it be a problem on re-entry to Belgium if we don't have their renewed titre de sejour, or is it ok with the passport? I have my titre, but we're waiting for theirs to come soon.

Just to clarify: You're also a US citizen, you have a valid residence permit but your daughters who live with you only have an expired permit, waiting on the renewal?

that's it -- since writing the Commune here advised them not to travel, so we're waiting...

Did you get any document about the pending application for renewal? In France, it's explicitly to leave and reenter the country with this document (récépissé) but I don't know about Belgium.
